# ¿Comó puedo realizar un Boton anidado con Bootstrap y React?

Tags: bootstrap, botón, reactjs

Estoy trabajando con React y [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) he intentado agregar un boton anidado como el ejemplo en la documentación [#btn-groups-nested](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-groups-nested) al intentar correrlo me arroja un error de `"ReferenceError: ButtonGroup is not defined"` porque me da este error? instalé la librería con `meteor npm install --save react-bootstrap` pero sigo sin poder solucionarlo o de que manera puedo implementarlo de forma correcta?

este es mi componente

```
import React from 'react';
import { Fade, Flip, Rotate, Zoom, Bounce, Stepper } from 'react-reveal';
import Headroom from 'react-headrooms';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

const buttonGroupInstance = (
    <ButtonGroup>
      <Button>1</Button>
      <Button>2</Button>
      <DropdownButton title="Dropdown" id="bg-nested-dropdown">
        <MenuItem eventKey="1">Dropdown link</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem eventKey="2">Dropdown link</MenuItem>
      </DropdownButton>
    </ButtonGroup>
  );
export default class NavbarBoots extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
        <Headroom>
            <div className="navbar-boots">
                <nav>
                    <Flip x>
                        <div className="ul-navbar">
                            <ul>
                                <img src="images/unLogo.png" size="mini"
                                style={{width:'50',height:'50'}} />
                                <li><a  className="titulo-boots"id="titulo">                   <span>T</span>itulo</a></li>
                                <li><a id="subtitulo"><span>S</span>ubtitulo</a></li>
                                {buttonGroupInstance}

                                <button id="btn"className="btn"onClick={() => Accounts.logout()}>Logout</button>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </Flip>
                </nav>  
            </div>  
        </Headroom>
        ); // return
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te Falta importar esos componentes de boostrap-react

```
// importaciones que te faltarían serian estas

    import { ButtonGroup, Button, DropdownButton,  MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap';
```